# Blank page on submit button

Tags: php, html, reload

I have some troubles with my html page. I want it to reload after pressing the submit button. I tried reloading it with javascript but it keeps on giving me a white page (after saving the data I need in a file).

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Web Form</title>
    </head>
<body>

<h1>Fill Out This Form</h1>


<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
<p><i>Choose one or more of the available options that represent the current mental state of the System:</i></p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mentalState[]" value="Knows user culture"> Knows User Culture<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mentalState[]" value="Knows concept "> Knows Concept<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mentalState[]" value="Knows that user knows concept"> Knows that User Knows Concept<br>


<p><i>Choose the corresponding action:</i></p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="action" value="cultureIdentif"> Culture Identification<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="action" value="conceptIdentif"> Concept Identification<br>


<p><i>Choose one or more of the available options that represent the current mental state of the System following the action:</i></p>

  <input type="checkbox" name="mentalState2[]" value="Knows user culture"> Knows User Culture<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mentalState2[]" value="Knows concept"> Knows Concept<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mentalState2[]" value="Knows that user knows concept"> Knows that User Knows Concept<br>
  </br>

  <input type="submit" value="Save Data">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the php code:

```
<?php


if(!empty($_POST['mentalState'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['mentalState'] as $mentalState)
        ($mentalState1=$mentalState . ',' . $mentalState1);
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['mentalState2'])){
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['mentalState2'] as $mentalState)
            ($mentalState2=$mentalState . ',' . $mentalState2);
        }


        if(isset($mentalState1) && isset($_POST['action']) && isset($mentalState2)) {
            $data = $mentalState1 . '-' . $_POST['action'] . '-' . $mentalState2 . "\n";
            $ret = file_put_contents('matrix.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            if($ret === false) {
                die('There was an error writing this file');
            }

    } else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Place `header( "Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']" ) ;` inside your last `IF` statement, when it completes without error it will redirect you back to the page you submitted from.

Comment: are you able to write the file ?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit.

Comment: Are the HTML and PHP in 2 seperate files?

Comment: Thanks I will edit the code format. Yes they are.

Comment: header( "Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']" ) is not working.
Syntax error due to the string 'HTTP_referer'
@Blinkydamo

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya it is writing in the file

Comment: @user2267486 ok , then please try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing one condition here

you have only

```
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
```

try to add the else and see

```
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
} else {
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see my update , i added your code to mine

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya This syntax worked for me:
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
thanks!

Comment: @user2267486 nice .  please mark the answer as accepted :) . i have updated my answer with your syntax

Comment: Ok DV removed. Much better, now it answers the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly , Thank you :)