# php header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");

Tags: php

I have a problem with this statement:

```
header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");
```

I am getting the following error:

Syntax error: unexpected 'location(T_STRING)'
This is the php file:

```
foreach($_POST['mentalState'] as $mentalState)
($mentalState1=$mentalState . ',' . $mentalState1);

}
else{

    $mentalState1="no information";
}


if(!empty($_POST['mentalState2'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['mentalState2'] as $mentalState)
($mentalState2=$mentalState . ',' . $mentalState2);
}

else{

    $mentalState2="no information";
}


if(isset($mentalState1) && isset($_POST['action']) && isset($mentalState2)) {
    $data = $mentalState1 . '-' . $_POST['action'] . '-' . $mentalState2 . "\n;
    $ret = file_put_contents('matrix.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }

  else {
  header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");
}
}

else {
   die('no post data to process');
}

}
```

p.s. I am working on cloud9
p.s.2 I tried to look up for existing answers but non of them seems to work for me.

Comment: if that's your real code, this `"\n;` is missing a quote and syntax highlighting is showing you there's a syntax error. You also should rely on HTTP_REFERER, it's not reliable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- "You also should rely on HTTP_REFERER, it's not reliable." make up your mind :-)

Comment: @Dagon I know, I'm being wishy washy.

Comment: i go some laundry you can washy washy if you like @Fred-ii-

Comment: Oh sure @Dagon put me through the spin cycle then the ringer ;-)

Comment: interestingly you had it right 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673778/blank-page-on-submit-button i suggest an IDE that will point theses things out to you.

Comment: @Dagon I know, all this is just magic for me. I have no idea why it works and why it doesn't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks fixed it in the code! What would be better than the HTTP_REFERER? thank you!